# warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds] in module

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, printk

```
static int myarray[2]={-1,234};
module_param_array(myarray,int,&arrayargc,0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(myarray,"Integer Array");

static int __init module_init_2(void)
{
 int i;
  for(i=0;i< (sizeof myarray/sizeof(int));i++);
{

printk(KERN_INFO "myarray[%d] is %d",i,myarray[i]);

}
```

I am writing a simple module to take some command line input.During compilation it is giving a warning

```
warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
printk(KERN_INFO "myarray[%d] is %d",i,myarray[i]);
```

Why is it giving warning as loop seems to be run till i=2, I saw some questions regarding this but that didn't help me so much

Comment: You forgot commas between `"Option#N ..."` strings. C takes it as a single string. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Does not even compile without a warning saying what is wrong.

Comment: I have made it correct. Now the problem is that the program prints the options then bypass the m=getchar and direct jumps to the next printf. Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: help vampire detected.

Comment: Cannot reproduce that, but BTW `char m;` should be `int m;` which is the type returned by `getchar()`.

Comment: @SaudFarooqui That's because you're using `scanf` for user input, which is a mistake. Also, there are about 500 duplicates of this question on SO.

Comment: I made it int m but still it is bypassing the m=getchar()

Comment: @melpomene could you elaborate your words

Comment: No. Don't use `scanf`.

Comment: Then what should i use isntead of scanf?

Comment: @melpomene could you please give me the link for the same problem'

Comment: You should use `fgets`. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scanf+skip

Comment: char *o,*m;       m=fgets(o,2,stdin);  but now it again makes segmentation fault

Comment: Having added the two missing commas, I cannot reproduce your next problem. Please ask a new question with the [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. "Complete" meaning your code can be copy/pasted into a text editor and compiled exactly as it is, to demonstrate the fault.

Answer (score 3):

Your very beginning `printf` specifies three `%s` for three strings, yet you provided just one string for that `printf`, and so the crash.

Note from Weather Vane comment:

**Remember that the C compiler will concatenate string literals which are separated only by whitespace.**

That means even though you wrote three separate "Option #1", "Option #2", etc. in three lines they still counted as just **one** string (after concatenation. Fix that by adding a comma at the end of each line to prevent concatenation (and so you'd have three separate strings).

Comment: Yes you are right, I added your comment which should explain the OP problem much clearer.

Comment: I like the way beginners generate "creative" bugs that you'd never think of. Almost art.

Comment: I have made it correct. Now the problem is that the program prints the options then bypass the m=getchar and direct jumps to the next printf. Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: `m` should be `int` for `getchar` - other than that it should work ok

Comment: I have made m int but still it is bypassing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I assumed you want to output both values that are successfully read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int period, time;

    const char micro_sec = 'u';
    const char mili_sec = 'm';
    const char sec = 's';

    printf("\nSelect unit of Time period: \n");

    printf("\nOption 1: %c for micro seconds\n"
             "Option 2: %c for mili seconds\n"
             "Option 3: %c for seconds\n", 
              micro_sec, mili_sec, sec);

    printf("\nEnter unit of Time Period: ");

    period = getchar();

    if (period == micro_sec || period == mili_sec || period == sec) {
        printf("Enter Time Period: ");

        if (scanf("%d", &time) != 1) {
            printf("Error reading time!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("\nUnit of time: %c\n", period);
        printf("Time Period: %d\n", time);

    } else {
        printf("\nIncorrect unit of time entered.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```